# ASP.NET set GridView update to CausesValidation = "false"

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

As the title suggests, I am attempting to set the UpdateMehod of a GridView to false. When the Update buttons is currently clicked, the event fires validation of a separate control, even though the separate control is in a separate validation group. The grid view is shown below:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="BikesItems" 
        runat="server"
        CssClass="table table-hover"
        ItemType="WLL.DAL.Bike"
        DataKeyNames="BikeID"
        SelectMethod="BikesItems_GetData"
        UpdateMethod="BikesItems_UpdateItem"
        DeleteMethod="BikesItems_DeleteItem"
        AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        ValidationGroup="BikeGrid">

        <Columns>
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="BikeID" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="BikeName" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="Description" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="ImgPath" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="Price" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="ManufacturerID" />

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

How do I set the CausesValidation to false for the update button, bearing in mind it is dynamically generated? Or does a more elegant solution exist? Thanks

Comment: Typically you would not disable the update function, but the validation group

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, bust is there a way to do this on the .aspx page?

Comment: Your'e not being very specific.  An aspx page is just markup.  but disabling a validation group can be done clientside with JS or serverside in the code behind.  It depends on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to disable the validation group in the code behind (server-side), Use `Page.GetValidators("ValidationGroup")` method.  You can pass in the name of the ValidationGroup and the method returns a `ValidatorCollection` over which you can iterate.

Or ClientSide, you can iterate over the `Page_Validators` array and check each validator group name that matches the group you're looking for and disable each as needed.